# Clean up State field with T-SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-update

The State field in our database is a mess.  There was no validation when it was filled so we have everything from two letter abbreviations to full state names to misspelled state names to "test" and "xxxx", etc.
I am not going to try to handle everything, but for sure I want to fix the correct state names to abbreviations.
I have a list of valid state names and abbreviations, but I don't know how I can do this:

```
UPDATE Table SET State = ('AR','AK') 
WHERE (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE State IN ('Arkansas','Alaska'))
```

Basically, can I update a field to be something from a list by the location it is in another list?

Comment: This may sidestep the answer your looking for, but, I'd probably do a select distinct State from Table to get the list of unique states and then do an update for each one... (like Update Table SET State = "TX" where State in ("Tx", "tx", "Texas", "Tex")...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you do have a lookup table with columns: State & Abbreviation

```
Update MyTable
from MyTable t1
Set State = (Select Abbreviation From OtherTable t2 where t1.State = t2.State)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement like this.

```
declare @T table ([State] varchar(20))

insert into @T values 
('Arkansas'),
('Arkansas'),
('Alaska'),
('None')

update @T set
[State] = case [State]
            when 'Arkansas' then 'AR'
            when 'Alaska' then 'AL'
            else [State]
          end
where
  [State] IN ('Arkansas','Alaska')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a lookup table (for the clean up and going forward to validate the entries) as BobTodd suggests but I would also create a temporary mapping table using

```
SELECT INTO State_Clean_Up
DISTINCT [State] as old_state_name, 'AAA' as new_state_name -- placeholder
FROM Your_Table
```

Now for the tedious bit, edit the mapping table and set all the `new_state_name` fields to their correct values based on the old names.

Update your table with a join on the mapping table.

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET [State] = new_state_name
FROM Your_Table INNER JOIN State_Clean_Up
ON Your_Table.State = State_Clean_Up.old_state_name
```

After the clean up (remember to back up your original data or, at least, use a transaction) you can drop the `State_Clean_Up` table.

**EDIT:** When you do the `SELECT DISTINCT...` part you could select the old name in to both columns and then you only have to edit the ones you want to clean up, all the others will remain the same, e.g.

```
SELECT INTO State_Clean_Up
DISTINCT [State] as old_state_name, [State] as new_state_name
FROM Your_Table
```